# Is there a way to have AppleScript output displayed in the menubar?

Tags: applescript, display, menu-bar

Before reading further:
I know about [butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/guide/english/help/triggermenu.html) and similar programs.  I am looking for a BUILT-IN way to do this without a third party app.

Anyway, I wrote an AppleScript that runs a shell command.  I want to display that output in the menubar at the top... without Butler how can I do this?

Comment: Since **AppleScriptObjC** is part of macOS  (2014) it is possible to use its "Foundation" framework (incl. NSMenu's methods) to achieve what was probably not possible in 2012. . . . . . See my answer below on How-to-do-it !

Answer (score 2):

As a generality, without a third party program, such as Growl, there is no built in way to do this.

However, you could write a script or other program such as one I found [here](http://t-a-w.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/personal-experience-points-and-osx.html) that provides the menulet service for you.  I'm sure that Growl integration would be much easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way to do this in OS X. However, using [Growl](http://growl.info/), you can have notifications. Here's a sample script for that:

```
--Make sure Growl is running
tell application "System Events"
    set isRunning to (count of (every process whose bundle identifier is "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp")) > 0
end tell

if isRunning then
    tell application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp"
        set the allNotificationsList to ¬
            {"Test Notification", "Another Test Notification"}
        --Notifications can be enabled in System Preferences>Growl>Applications>Display Options
        set the enabledNotificationsList to ¬
            {"Test Notification"}
        register as application ¬
            "Growl AppleScript Sample" all notifications allNotificationsList ¬
            default notifications enabledNotificationsList ¬
                    -- Set the icon. You can use any icon from any application
            icon of application "AppleScript Editor"

        notify with name ¬
            "Test Notification" title ¬
            "Test Notification" description ¬
            "This is a test AppleScript notification." application name "Growl AppleScript Sample"

        notify with name ¬
            "Another Test Notification" title ¬
            "Another Test Notification :) " description ¬
            "Alas — you won't see me until you enable me..." application name "Growl AppleScript Sample"

    end tell
end if
```

That should display this:

[image]

And if you have the other notification enabled too:

[image]
[image]

More advanced techniques are described [here.](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since **AppleScriptObjC** is part of macOS it is possible to use its "Foundation" framework (incl. NSMenu's methods) to achieve what was probably not possible in 2012.

I found an interesting script to create custom menus from within AppleScript; from this I extracted suitable code to ***place text in macOS's menu bar***. In fact it uses just a menu's "title" for inserting some content.

In order to demonstrate this I implemented a very basic dialog script that asks users for text input (waiting 6 sec.) which is then displayed in the menu bar temporarily (5 sec.).
*Here it is:*

```
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions
property StatusItem : missing value
property newMenu : class "NSMenu"

display dialog "Write something:" default answer "" giving up after 6
set myText to text returned of the result
if myText is "" then set myText to "TOOOOO slow … try again !"
set myText to ">>    " & myText & "    <<"

set bar to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar
set StatusItem to bar's statusItemWithLength:-1.0
StatusItem's setTitle:myText
set newMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Custom"
StatusItem's setMenu:newMenu

delay 5
current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s ¬
        removeStatusItem:StatusItem
```

*This AppleScript code can be used in any script of yours. (Its "dialog" part is optional…)*

[user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) *helped with closing my "menu", see last line of the script. Thanks a lot!*

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to the original source code you derived your answer from? It would be nice to see. Thanks.

Comment: Yes – it's in the last handler of the accepted answer to this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168474/creating-a-simple-menubar-app-using-applescript` . . . . . I am afraid though, that my last line (works half of the time) that I found somewhere else –and adapted– is _NOT correct_ . . . . . . I am not a programmer so I need some more time to understand code.

Comment: BTW It's a nice answer and if not for "it crashed a few times – because of "dealloc()" ?" I would have +1. Some food for thought though... if you use this code as a stand alone AppleScriptObjC app, maybe that would be better, then `StatusItem's dealloc()` is only applicable to the AppleScriptObjC app and not Script Editor and accidentally crashing it.

Comment: FWIW The first `set myText to ...` line of _code_, the one before `display dialog` _command_ really does nothing based on the ensuing code and therefore is not at all needed. In other words, the only used _value_ of `myText` is that which is assigned after the `display dialog` _command_ is _run_ and why setting it to anything prior to the the `display dialog` _command_ is unused coding and not necessary in the context of the _code_ currently presented.

Comment: Instead of `StatusItem's dealloc()` or `StatusItem's setTitle:""` I'd use: `current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s removeStatusItem:StatusItem`

Comment: Returned: `error "NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!" number -10000`.