# AppleScript : write text on menu bar

Tags: macos, applescript

I wonder if AppleScript can print a variable in the top menu bar in OSX 10.11 ?

Comment: Can you provide some details?

Comment: Maybe, but not that I know of. Access so far as I know is one way: using GUI scripting to interact with elements in the menu bar that already exist. I don't know about "writing" to the menu bar. There might be some hackey workarounds, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes thank you, I guess I need to code a swift menu bar app, and then add my applescript in it

Comment: @KevinCork I know with Xcode it's possible to display something up there, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way, using **AppleScriptObjC** as [described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42037/is-there-a-way-to-have-applescript-output-displayed-in-the-menubar):

```
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions
property StatusItem : missing value
property newMenu : class "NSMenu"
-- myVariable derived from whatever code >>

set myVariable to ">>  " & "Output of script: value of variable." & "  <<"

set bar to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar
set StatusItem to bar's statusItemWithLength:-1.0
StatusItem's setTitle: myVariable
set newMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Custom"
StatusItem's setMenu:newMenu

delay 5
current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s ¬
        removeStatusItem:StatusItem
```

*On the original page I posted code that gets a display-dialog's return & puts it onto the menu bar.*

Comment: Returned: `error "NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!" number -10000`.

Comment: Hi, sadly my elderly MacBook Air ist still running High Sierra 10.13.6. I do not get any errors and the menu bar's output is: " >> Output of script: value of variable. << ".